# Jquery draggable & droppable event delegation: stop & drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

My problem is to get the position of the dropped element.
I use `stop:`option on `.draggable`to get the new position.

```
$('.elementsDiv').draggable({
  revert: 'invalid', //Revert when drop fails
  helper: 'clone', //Drag a clone
  stop: function() {
    //Dropped position.
    Stoppos = $(this).position();
  }
});
```

When dragged i'd like to remove the element from it's parent, and append it to it´s new parent.
This i do with `.droppable`

```
$('.flakUp, .flakDown').droppable({
    accept: '.elementsDiv',
    drop: function (event, ui) {

        //get dragged element
        var draggedElement = $(ui.draggable);

        //get dropZone
        var dropZone = $(this); 

        //Remove element from list and append it to dropZone
        draggedElement.detach().appendTo(dropZone.position(Stoppos));

        //Make element draggable
        draggedElement.draggable();
    }
});
```

When i remove/append, the new position will be top-left.
So i must get the dropped position from `.draggable` and use it in `.droppable` drop function to move the element to where it was dropped.

This is where my problem starts!
In console i get: Stoppos is not defined.
I guess the droppable-drop executes before draggable-stop?!

How can i solve this?
I need to create a clone, because of index problems. Therefore i also need to remove/append the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise making use of the attributes of the function that are passed.

```
var stopPos = {};
var stopOff = {};

$('.elementsDiv').draggable({
  revert: 'invalid', //Revert when drop fails
  helper: 'clone', //Drag a clone
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    stopPos = ui.position;
    stopOff = ui.offest;
    console.log(stopPos, stopOff);
  }
});
```

This will give you the Position and Offset of the helper as `{top, left}` object. You can use these later when you're attaching the helper in your droppable.

```
$('.flakUp, .flakDown').droppable({
  accept: '.elementsDiv',
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    var draggedElement = $(ui.draggable);
    var dropZone = $(this); 

    //Remove element from list and append it to dropZone
    draggedElement.detach().appendTo(dropZone.position(stopPos));

     //Make element draggable
     draggedElement.draggable();
  }
});
```

So nothing outwardly wrong with your code, but notice one small thing, is the definition of the variable `stopPos` and `stopOff` outside of the functions. In the end it should look like:

```
  $(function(){
    var stopPos = {};
    var stopOff = {};

    $('.elementsDiv').draggable({
      revert: 'invalid', //Revert when drop fails
      helper: 'clone', //Drag a clone
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        stopPos = ui.position;
        stopOff = ui.offest;
        console.log(stopPos, stopOff);
      }
    });

    $('.flakUp, .flakDown').droppable({
      accept: '.elementsDiv',
      drop: function (event, ui) {
        var draggedElement = $(ui.draggable);
        var dropZone = $(this); 

        //Remove element from list and append it to dropZone
        draggedElement.detach().appendTo(dropZone.position(stopPos));

         //Make element draggable
         draggedElement.draggable();
      }
    });
  });
```

In this method, the variables can be accessed by both. if you only define it inside of the function, it is not accessible to other functions.